# how to disapear whatever

Tags: linux, scheduling, policy

This code shows to user the scheduling policy and the priority for every active process in linux.

```
#!/bin/bash
ps|awk '{print $1}' > temp.txt 
sed -i '/PID/'d ./temp.txt #deletes the first line that contains the word 'PID'
x=$(wc -w temp.txt|awk '{print $1}') #counts file's lines
for ((i=1;i<=$x;++i)) #for every pid executes the command chrt seperately
do
chrt -p $i > file_$i.txt #moves the result in a new file
y=$(wc -w file_$i.txt|awk '{print $1}') 
if [ y=2 ] #the results not containing errors are two lines, so i use the    command 'cat' to show the successful ones
then
    cat file_$i.txt
    rm file_$i.txt
else
        rm file_$i.txt
    fi
done
```

When I run it I get this:

```
pid 1's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER
pid 1's current scheduling priority: 0
pid 2's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER
pid 2's current scheduling priority: 0
chrt: failed to get pid 3's policy: No such process
pid 4's current scheduling policy: SCHED_OTHER
pid 4's current scheduling priority: 0
```

How can I hide this failed line(chrt: failed to get pid 3's policy: No such process) so when somoene run my code dont showing fails?

Comment: Add `2>/dev/null` to redirect the error output at the end of your chrt line (well before the comments!).  Or better yet, send it out to a log file (`2>somelogfile`) so you will know when chrt fails on something.

Comment: `yourScript | perl -ne 'print if not /failed/` is one way to go....but...there's a comment that the existing script is already trying to remove failures and without seeing the output at that point in the script, it's hard to say why it's not working.  Although @Nic3500 has a better plan, I'd say.